# Unable to Create AIDL Folder in Flutter Android Project

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]
I am developing an Android application using the Flutter framework, and I need to integrate it with a POS (Point of Sale) device. The POS device company has provided instructions for this integration, which involve creating an AIDL (Android Interface Definition Language) folder within the Android folder of my Flutter project.

Following their instructions, I attempted to create the AIDL folder, but I encountered an issue. Android Studio shows the error message "project not ready (requires minSdk >=16)." I tried adjusting the minSdkVersion in the build.gradle file of my project, but the issue persists.

Here's what I have tried so far:

Adjusting the minSdkVersion in build.gradle.
Checking for any conflicting settings in other project files.
Verifying the project structure to ensure it meets the requirements.
Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to create the AIDL folder as instructed.